# How to get a certain (e.g. second or third) mention sent in a message

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I've been trying to make a ship command that can either ship the author of the message with a mentioned user, or ship two mentioned users. I can get the 1st mention in a message but I have no idea on how to get the 2nd or even third mention in a message. I tried using:

`message.mentions.users.first(2)`

splitting the args then slicing them so only the second mention is avalaible, but this gives an `"undefined"` error when I try to get the username.

Could someone give me a script on exactly how to do it since I can't really get the hang of this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/blob/stable/src/structures/MessageMentions.js#L47) `message.mentions.users` yields a [Collection](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection). So you can just iterate over this collection or convert it to an array and then access the required index:

```
const userArray =  message.mentions.users.array();
console.log(userArray[yourDesiredIndex]);
```